# Returning one object with the result of two AJAX GET calls

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a simple weather app that will grab both the current and the weekly forecast from a weather API. To keep it simple, I'd really like to my `weatherService` function, `getForecast`, to somehow make two AJAX calls -- one for the weekly forecast, which I already have, and one for the current forecast (unfortunately I don't think this API has a means of retrieving a JSON return that contains both). I'm not sure about the best way to go about doing this, I'm very new to Angular.

Here's my service:

```
weather.service('weatherService', function($resource, $http){

    this.currentForecast = null;

    // default city
    this.city = 'Chicago, IL';

    this.getForecast = function(location, type) {

            return $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q="+location+"&mode=json&cnt=7&appid=e92f550a676a12835520519a5a2aef4b"
            }).then(
                 function(response) {
                     return response.data;
                 }
            )
    };

});
```

And I'd like a second GET, retrieving from: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chicago,IL&appid=e92f550a676a12835520519a5a2aef4b to be appended to the response, so that there's a single object returned.

Also, if this isn't the best way to go about doing this, I'm certainly open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is angular promises library [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
$q.all([$http(...), $http(...),...]).then(function(ret){
    // ret has all results from all ajax calls         
})
```

More specifically:

```
weather.service('weatherService', function($resource, $http, $q){

  this.getForecast = function(location, type) {
     return $q.all([
         $http.get(url1(location, type)), 
         $http.get(url2(location, type))
     ])
  }

})


...


weatherService.getForcast(location, type).then(function(ret){ 
    console.log(ret[0].data)
    console.log(ret[1].data)     
})
```

There is excellent video on using $q.all at [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-q-all)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use webworkers,  but then you have 6 problems.  You can also chain requests using `then` callbacks.